# Properly referencing controls in ASP.NET user controls in JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls

I have an ASP.NET user control that contains a text box control and a button control.  This user control will be added to my web-page many times.  I need to have a piece of JavaScript that will run whenever the text box changes, and disable the button if the value of the text box is invalid.  My question is this: how do I put JavaScript on the textbox that can reference only the button that is in the same user control?  Remember, there are many ASP.NET user controls, each with a button and a text box, and I only want the invalid value in a text box to affect the one associated button.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ClientId property of controls (it's uniquely identifies control on the client side) and make something like that:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" Text="click" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("<%=myTextBox.ClientID %>").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("<%=myButton.ClientID %>").disabled = "disabled";
    }
</script>
```

Also refer to this document:
[Client Script in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx), section **Referencing Server Controls in Client Script**