# Multiple User Control On Same Page And reference issue with Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls, reference, multiple-instances

I have one  usercontrol which contain one textbox, few buttons and one calander.
I had place two instance of user control in one page as design time. It works fine all working from server side...mean server side events reference proper control at runtime.

Problem start after raising server side events from javascript. I succeed to fire proper event from javascript as per suggetion from [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384867/properly-referencing-controls-in-asp-net-user-controls-in-javascript). Still I am not able to reference specific control at server side event. It always reference to control of last user control placed on page.

In my senerio I am firing calander's selected change event by buttons click event from javascript. The event fires as I want, but always it reference to last usercontrol's Calander.

*Firing server side events from jabvascript is one step towards performance of user control.*

Please suggest me.

Comment: Could you post some code please

Comment: Here, as i mentioned above all working fine if I work with control's server side events. But, when I remove server side events and deal with javascript and call server side events from javascript then it always refer to last user control placed on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On button click event call function of specific button and find calendar by id.